# my pieChart in shiny not working or showing anything

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I wrote somecode in Shiny with R. However, whatever I'm trying, my pieChart is not showing.
Is it my data or the code that is wrong?
The data for the chart looks like this:

value name
 dbl chr
    17 Species
    10 Movies
     8 Tv Series
     6 Games
     5 Food
    46 Random

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(title = "Catnames in Europe"),
    skin = "red",

        dashboardSidebar(
                img(src = "cats_looking.jpg", height = 100, width = 150, align = "left"),
                selectInput("countries",
                            "Choose country:",
                            choices = c("Netherlands","Germany","Turkey","Ireland",
                                    "England","Belgium","Spain","Portugal",
                                    "United Sates","Denmark","Sweden",
                                    "Switzerland","Italy"),
                            selected = "Netherlands",
                            multiple = FALSE,
                            width = '400px'),
              selectInput("years",
                        "Choose Year:",
                        choices = c("2017","2018","2019","2020"),
                        selected = "2019",
                        multiple = FALSE,
                        width = '400px'),
                actionButton("button","Update view",style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
              tags$div(div_id= "distPie", class ="plot-Output")
              ),
        dashboardBody(fluidRow(
            tabBox(
                tabPanel("Countries",tableOutput("catnametable"),
                     style = "background-color: #ffffff;")),
            tabBox(
                tabPanel("Years",tableOutput("years"),
                     style = "background-color: #ffffff;"),
                tabPanel("Trends in 2019",deliverChart(div_id = "pieChart", running_in_shiny = TRUE),
                         style = "background-color: #ffffff;"))
    )))
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$catnametable <- renderTable({
        countrylist <- CatnamesEurope %>%
            filter(Country %in% input$countries)
    })
    output$years <- renderTable({
        yearlist <- Years2 %>%
            filter(Years_ordered %in% input$years)
    })
    output$pieChart <- renderPieChart(
        div_id = "pieChart",
        data = Trends,
        radius = '75%',
        center_x = '50%',
        center_y = '50%',
        show.label = TRUE,
        show.legend = TRUE, show.tools = TRUE,
        font.size.legend= 12
    )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi, you should add a little bit of informations on your request: what are `Years2` and `CatnamesEurope` objects? ( I guess that the data you talked about is the `Trends` object, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to try.

I commented out some `output` statements as I didn't have all your data.

I also added:

```
loadEChartsLibrary(),
tags$div(id="pieChart", style="width:100%;height:400px;"),
```

Before you called `deliverChart`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(ECharts2Shiny)

Trends <- data.frame(
  value = c(17,10,8,6,5,46),
  name = c("Species", "Movies", "TV Series", "Games", "Food", "Random"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Catnames in Europe"),
  skin = "red",

  dashboardSidebar(
    img(src = "cats_looking.jpg", height = 100, width = 150, align = "left"),
    selectInput("countries",
                "Choose country:",
                choices = c("Netherlands","Germany","Turkey","Ireland",
                            "England","Belgium","Spain","Portugal",
                            "United Sates","Denmark","Sweden",
                            "Switzerland","Italy"),
                selected = "Netherlands",
                multiple = FALSE,
                width = '400px'),
    selectInput("years",
                "Choose Year:",
                choices = c("2017","2018","2019","2020"),
                selected = "2019",
                multiple = FALSE,
                width = '400px'),
    actionButton("button","Update view",style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
    tags$div(div_id= "distPie", class ="plot-Output")
  ),
  dashboardBody(fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      tabPanel("Countries",tableOutput("catnametable"),
               style = "background-color: #ffffff;")),
    tabBox(
      tabPanel("Years",tableOutput("years"),
               style = "background-color: #ffffff;"),
      tabPanel("Trends in 2019", 
               loadEChartsLibrary(),
               tags$div(id="pieChart", style="width:100%;height:400px;"),
               deliverChart(div_id = "pieChart", running_in_shiny = TRUE),
               style = "background-color: #ffffff;"))
  )))
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$catnametable <- renderTable({
    #countrylist <- CatnamesEurope %>%
    #  filter(Country %in% input$countries)
  })
  output$years <- renderTable({
    #yearlist <- Years2 %>%
    #  filter(Years_ordered %in% input$years)
  })

  output$pieChart <- renderPieChart(
    div_id = "pieChart",
    data = Trends,
    radius = '75%',
    center_x = '50%',
    center_y = '50%',
    show.label = TRUE,
    show.legend = TRUE, show.tools = TRUE,
    font.size.legend= 12
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```